Spring MVC Controller not displaying view
So I worked on a spring boot app and I have been struggling to make my view and my controller connect. Is there something that I did wrong ?
Main.java
package projetJpa.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Main implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }


}

HomeControler.java
package projetJpa.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import projetJpa.dao.Dao;

@Controller()
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeControler {

    @RequestMapping("")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        return new ModelAndView("index");
    }

}

So it should return my view index.jsp but I keep getting the error : "Whitelabel Error Page".

Did you set spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp ?

Please provide your setup of the template engine.

@WladimirDiskowski I did : spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
And my index.jsp is in /WEB-INF/jsp

Although the following shouldn't be a problem in your case, since Spring WEB changed its behavior regarding trailing slashes, please try: @RequestMapping without ("/") for the HomeControler [fyi typo in Crontroler], and @GetMapping({"", "/"}) for the index() route.

@Slevin I tried to change RequestMapping and GetMapping for the index() route but I still have this error : Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Apr 01 14:02:13 CEST 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
Where do I configure the template engine that you asked ?

I figured it out ! @Slevin The correct path wasn't "/" but "/projetJpa", do you know how I can configure this ?
